# Elementary os freya installer does not recognize existing OS and partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, elementaryos

I have tried to install Elementary os freya on my laptop but in the partioning step it shows me a blank disk drive: 750 gb on unallocated space.
when I start gparted (still in elementary os live usb) it shows me the same: a blank disk drive: 750 gb on unallocated space.

When I restart my laptop and remove the usb, it boots pretty normal, I have a dual boot with antergos (arch based distro) and windows 10
the partition table can be read from both systems without any issue.

I can't figure out what is the matter with Elementary os installer

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/1049444/521843 look at this. Can this also be an issue with the partition style? And how would you like to install Elementary? On a seperate partition? If you make an Ubuntu install USB, does that recognize the partitions?

Comment: By the way: why are you asking this here? There is a whole Elementary OS community on Stack Exchange. Maybe you will find answers there. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/