# Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to install Windows 10 in my laptop. I am not allowed to install on any of drive. It keep through error of "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style"

I have read many blogs and solution but all suggest to clean the disk buy command. This way I will lost data of all other partitions as well.

I just want to install in single partition. Can any body please suggest me how to get solve this without losing data of other partition?

Comment: In your last piece of text: did you mean drive or partition? You want to install it on drive or partition?

Comment: @mpboom I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: Is it really not an option to backup your data and format your drive? If you cant boot your PC up, you can make an USB with Elementary OS (elementary.io) and the program Rufus and copy the data via there.

Comment: @mpboom I can't move the data(back up). Can you please suggest me any other way. I have read somewhere about to use Rufus. But the information was not enough to solve the issue.

Comment: Just download on a Windows PC this: https://rufus.akeo.ie, and download the Elementary OS ISO from here: https://elementary.io/. Now create with Rufus and the ISO a bootable USB. Boot your PC from that USB and choose 'Try Elementary' (wont install Elementary). Now copy your files. You can also burn the Elementary ISO to a DVD if that is an option. Let me know if you have any questions left.

Answer (score -2):

Cleanly installing windows (any version 7 and up) on a GPT partitioned drive requires a UEFI motherboard setup to boot via UEFI, and a UEFI Windows boot CD or USB flash drive. When the install disk boots via UEFI then you will be able to install windows on a GPT disk. Otherwise, it will fail because, GPT disks require UEFI to boot off of them as traditional bios only supports booting to MBR partitioned disks.

Comment: This seems more like a comment.  The reason I say this because you don't explain HOW to solve the author's problem.

Comment: Exactly what @Ramhound said. This is not an answer, merely a hint, and hints need to go as comments :-)