# How to copy data to portable hard disk?

Tags: installation, backup

I am installing windows 10. I am in the situation where I need to format Hard Drive. I have formatted OS Partition by mistake.

Can anybody suggest me how to copy data of other partition? I have portable Hard Disk.

Comment: You need an operating system.  It can be as simple as a Live Linux Environment,   Why did you format your OS partition?

Comment: @Ramhound I have described my issue here lastly. http://superuser.com/questions/1049444/windows-cannot-be-installed-to-this-disk-the-selected-disk-is-of-the-gpt-partit?noredirect=1#comment1470103_1049444

Comment: So instead of creating a EFI compatible installation media, you decided to format the system partition, boot to a Linux live environment and copy the files.

Comment: But I am not getting solution. My work delayed due to this. Can you suggest me shorter way? I have tried as people suggest me in that Ticket.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to Create EFI compatible installation pendrive? I am new here. I have Rufus program and windows-10 installation files.

Comment: Rufus is how you would create it.

Comment: @Ramhound In Target System Type, I have tried by all 3. 1- MBR with BIOS or UEFI, 2-   MBR with UEFI and 3- GPT with UEFI. 1st option can progress till select drive to installation but it through same error. 2nd and 3rd option doesn't progress even. Please suggest if any other way is possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36803/discussion-between-nj-bhanushali-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

The OS partition cannot be formatted originally! It is too bad that you format your OS partition. If you want to copy data of other partition, here I recommend you a very simple backup software AOMEI Backupper, which can help you backup data of other partitions to your portable hard drive by a few clicks with its easy to use interface. Even you are a computer noob, you can operate it alone without losing data. first, connect your portable hard drive to your Windows computer, launch the software, and select Clone->Partition Clone, then, select the partition you want to Clone, and select the portable hard drive as the destination disk,click Next. finally, click Start Clone, it will copy the data on the partition to your portable hard drive.

Answer (score -2):

If you install win 10 or any other os on empty partition your new os will recognize old partition where are your files and then you just copy that